# image not showing in prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I am using prettyphoto for gallery.For the purpose when i click cover image of album the images of that album is shown via prettyphoto.Everything is working fine except the image is not showing.
Code:
html

```
<div id="album_5" class="album_images" style="display:none">
<div class="albumimgs">
<a albumid="5" title="" href="http://localhost/sharepoint/image/album/1000/0/album_309_1379593500.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[5]">
<img src="http://localhost/sharepoint/image/album/400/400/album_309_1379593500.jpg">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here 5 is album Id.

JavaScript code:

```
$('img').live('click', function(){ //click the album cover img
  var parents = $(this).parents('div.albums');
  var albumId = parents.find('a').attr('rel');
  var url = 'js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js';
  $.getScript(url)
     .done(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto["+albumId+"]']").prettyPhoto({
            theme:'pp_kalypso',
            deeplinking: false
       });
       $('div#album_'+albumId).find('a[albumid="'+albumId+'"]').trigger('click');
  });
})
```

The div portion of prettyphoto() where image must be shown is null.
any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Is it showing any error in console

Comment: @muthu No .... no error in console

Comment: can u print the value prettyPhoto["+albumId+"]']

Comment: @muthu when alerted in javascript it alerts [object Object]. Is this the error?

Comment: No.It is not an error. Could u add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: what do you get in albumId

Comment: @muthu I get the required image name.

Comment: is this ok for u http://jsfiddle.net/797jh/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sammy, i think the possibility is that you have multiple images with the same value for albumid. So when you trigger the click for prettyPhoto all of them gets clicked.

Try to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) as

```
$('div#album_'+albumId).find('a[albumid="'+albumId+'"]:eq(0)').trigger('click');
```

OR

```
$('div#album_'+albumId).find('a[albumid="'+albumId+'"]:first').trigger('click');
```

Enjoy....